# Taskbar on all monitors

Tags: 17.10, ubuntu-gnome

The new GNOME desktop in Ubuntu 17.10 doesn't have a setting to put the taskbar on all monitors. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install an extension, such as [Multiple Monitor Panels](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/323/multiple-monitor-panels/) to be able to configure this.

Comment: Unfortunately that one was last updated 6 years ago and recent comments warn it doesn't work.